# How to use route's params in adapter in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

Imagine we have an app that allows a user to collect cards and make decks of their cards.

Also, imagine we have in router:

```
this.route('cards');
this.route('decks', function() {
    this.route('deck', {path: ':deck_name'});
});
```

And two API endpoints:

1. `GET /cards` — to query all cards controlled by a user
2. `GET /decks/:deck_name/cards` — to query all cards in the deck with certain `deck_name` controlled by a user

We have a model of `card` and want to make different requests depending on the current route *(to the first endpoint for our app's `/cards` route, and to second for `/decks/:deck_name` route)*.

## **How to write an adapter for `card` model to query the right endpoint depending on the route?**

In other words, how to use **one** Ember Model (for cards) and point DS Adapter **to different** endpoints (e.g., by changing adapter's `namespace`) depending on the current route in Ember web app?

---

We use Ember v2.18.

Comment: Your ember routes have *nothing* to do with your API routes.

Comment: Do you want to use plain ajax / fetch or do you plan to use [ember-data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/) and it's relationships?

Comment: @jelhan I plan to use ember-data.
I am asking basically two questions:
1) How can I use one Ember Model (for cards) and point DS Adapter to different endpoints (e.g., by changing adapter's namespace) depending on the current route in Ember web app?
2) How to access route's param (e.g., :deck_name) in DS Adapter.

Comment: @Lux Yes, routes have nothing to do with API routes. Correct.

Comment: Does your API implement JSON API specification? If so: Do you have an endpoint `GET /decks/:deck_name`? Does it support `include` query param?

Comment: @jelhan Thank you for your questions! 1) Let's assume it is JSON API. 2) No, there is no such endpoint. 3) No, there is no support for such query param.

Comment: Do you have a model `deck`? Does it have a relationship with `card`?

Comment: @jelhan Yes, thanks, there is model `deck` with relationship to `card`.

Comment: Any reason you are not using ember-data's magic to load the related records? Each relationship provides a Promise that resolves with the related records.

Comment: @jelhan I would love to! But the problem that Ember Data's magic will query the wrong endpoint (`/cards`) when user at `/decks/:deck_name` route. I want to help that magic and customize the path also using `:deck_name` param from the route.

Answer (score 0):

As agreed in comments we assume that your API implements [JSON API specification](https://jsonapi.org/).

If I got you right, you have a `decks` model which has a one-to-many relationship to `cards` model. A [resource object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects) returned by your API for a `decks` record should include [relationships object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) for that relationship. This may either provide a [related resource link](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links), which allows to fetch the related records or providing a list of [resource identifiers](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects) through [resource linkage](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage).

A resource object implementing both looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "decks",
  "id": "1",
  "relationships": {
    "cards": {
      "links": {
        // related resource link
        // specification is agnostic about how this URL may look like
        "related": "https://examples.com/api/decks/1/cards"
      },
      // resource linkage
      "data": [
        { "type": "cards", "id": "1" },
        { "type": "cards", "id": "2" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If your API includes this information, you could fetch the related records using the relationship. Ember-data will use the related resource link or fetch the linked resources by ID. Ember Data supports [coalescing of find requests](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Adapter/properties/coalesceFindRequests?anchor=coalesceFindRequests) to reduce the number of requests needed to fetch related records by ID.

E.g. assuming you have these two models:

```
// app/models/deck.js
export Model.extend({
  cards: hasMany()
});

// app/models/card.js
export Model.extend({
  deck: belongsTo()
});
```

A model hook for a route that needs all cards of a specific deck could look like this:

```
export Route.extend({
  model({ deck_name }) {
    return this.store.findRecord('deck', deck_name).then((deck) => {
      deck.get('cards');
    });
  }
});
```

If your relationship is not setup well or if your backend does not include a related resource link nor resource linkage or if you don't want to take the overhead of another request, you have to do so work manually. I guess this would mean to fetch the data using your custom endpoint and push it to the store using it's [`push()` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Store/methods/push?anchor=push). You should deserialize it before using your models Serializer.